# How to get user login of a particular GitHub pull request using Octokit?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, github, octokit

I am able to get the login name for the current authenticated user using

```
octokitClient.User.Current()
```

Given the parameters such as "repo owner", "repo name" and "pull request ID", is there any way to retrieve the login name, github username and email using Octokit? Thank you.

```
pullRequestResponse["user"]["login"]
```

Comment: You won't be able to get the email address if the user hasn't set it to public, not even if you're the owner of an org the user belongs to.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I am able to get the email from `https://{GitHub Host Name}/api/v3/repos/{repo owner}/{repo name}/pulls/{PR id}/commits`. And then `response[0]["commit"]["author"]["email"]`

Comment: That's the commit email, which a user can choose to set to an anonymized one; what I meant is that there is no way to retrieve a users' primary GitHub email address from the API

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out how to get the login name (but still can't find username and email)

```
var listOfPullRequest = await octokitClient.PullRequest.GetAllForRepository(...);
var login = listOfPullRequest[0].User.Login;
```